# drag and drop problem

Tags: mfc

I have an Application and want to drop a file in it. I used the COleDropTarget class and derived from it. In my CMainFrame class in the methode OnCreate I register it. This return true.

When OnDrop gets called `pDataObject->GetFileData(CF_TEXT);` or even `pDataObject->IsDataAvailable(CF_TEXT)` returns 0.

Can someone tell me why?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dropping a file doesn't have the data type CF_TEXT but CF_HDROP.
You have to check for that and then extract the file paths from the CF_HDROP structure.

To get the paths from the CF_HDROP structure, use the [DragQueryFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776408%28VS.85%29.aspx) API.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
I did what you told and IsDataAvailable return 1. thats good.
But how do I extract data from CF_HDROP? (Because this is defined as 15 in winuser.h and not a structure)
and after this CFile* file =pDataObject->GetFileData(CF_HDROP);
file->m_strFileName has the value ""